# Android App/ to paly audio/videos files from Raw or Assets folder instead of /SDCard/

Tags: java, android, audio, video, media-player

Please anyone could help me getting this Android App play audio /video files from Raw or Assets Folders instead playing from /SDCard/.

What should I change in this code below ?

Here is the [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) code.

regards.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
// SDCard Path

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")

final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files from sdcard and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put(
                    "songTitle",
                    file.getName().substring(0,
                            (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

/**
 * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
 * */
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try this for loading files from Assets folder..
Consider there is ringtone folder inside assets folder then use in your activity

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getResources().getAssets();
String[] files = null;
try {
files = assetManager.list("ringtone"); //ringtone is folder name
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: " + e.toString());
}
```

so u get the files from assets folder next get file name and pass files names to your list

Answer (score 0):

**To Play Audio From Raw Folder:**

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song.mp3);
```

**To Play Audio From Asset Folder:**

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("Song.mp3");
player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```